# Приложение вылетает после присвоения данных к переменной

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

У меня есть функция которая сохраняет данные на имя введенное в поле (EditText). Так же при старте это поле заполняется автоматический последним использованным именем. Без авто-заполнения поля все работала идеально, но после того как я написал эту функцию приложение стало вылетать. Но самое странное то что если я в коде присваиваю переменной filename (в которой должно было быть имя) имя в ручную то все работает. Хотя пытался выводить с авто-заполненного поля через Toast, то имя выводилось корректно. Проблема судя по всему в взаимодействии строки извлечённой из поля с авто-заполнением и сохранением во внутренние хранилище.

- Функция авто-заполнения при старте работает просто, берет имя также из внутреннего хранилища (openFileInput, read и т.д.), которое было сохранено туда в прошлый раз и с помощью .setText() заполняет поле
- Так же я пробовал брать имя напрямую из внутреннего хранилища, но проблема была полностью идентичной, полностью.

  ```
  fun saveResults(view: View) {

  //Берёт имя из поля для ввода в котором текст введен с помощью .setText()

  val showName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.saveName) as EditText

  var filename: String = showName.text.toString()

  //Если в этом месте присвоить переменной filename любую строку в ручную, то тогда все будет работать как надо, то есть filename = "Gena"

  //Дата

  val getDate = Date()
  val stringDate: String = getDate.toString()
  val date = stringDate.split(" ")

  //Создаёт строку с данными, в будущем при извлечении будет разделена с..
  //..помощью .split("_")

  var string: String = aText + "_" + date[2] + "_" + date[1] + "_" + date[5]

  //Сохраняет данные на имя из поле

  var fos: FileOutputStream

  fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
  fos.write(string.toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
  fos.close()

  //Показывает тост с подтверждением сохранения

  Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to $filename", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
  ```

(Код на Котлин, пишу в Андройд Студио, тестирую как в эмуляторе на версии Андройд 8.0, так же на реальном девайсе. Я начинающий, особенно на Котлин и Андройд и это моя первое приложение.)

Спасибо заранее всем за ответы.

P.S. Вот логи:

```
                                                                   --------- beginning of crash
09-09 19:12:46.182 4100-4100/com.aleko2104.bloodpressure E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.aleko2104.bloodpressure, PID: 4100
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
                                                                               at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:215)
                                                                               at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileOutput(ContextImpl.java:535)
                                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:195)
                                                                               at com.aleko2104.bloodpressure.ResultActivity.saveResults(ResultActivity.kt:263)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Если у вас "вылетает", приложите стектрейс при падении приложения

Comment: После проверки определил, что вылетает при первом же использовании переменной.  Мозг сломал уже, даже близко не вижу в чем проблема...

Comment: приложите логи.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, добавил логи

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path` как бы намекает что у Вас неверный путь к файлу

Comment: `openFileOutput` принимает только имя файла без поддиректорий (то есть слэшей: / ). Смотрите во что форматируется дата - проблема вероятно в ней.

Comment: Дата не входит в имя файла, в имя файла входит обычно что то типа '"a"' или '"Igor"', а дата записывается в формате '"10_Sept_2017"' уже на это имя. Но я примерно понял в чем проблема. Я думаю что проблема в том, что имя файла может быть только определенной кодировки, то есть когда поле, из которого потом и берется имя файла, заполняется из внутреннего хранилища, а при извлечении этой строки оттуда строка меняет кодировку 'buffer.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())'. Хотя я не уверен

Comment: Нормальная кодировка для Андроида utf-8 и defaultCharset, по идее должен отдавать именно её. В любом случае в имя файла попадают какие-то недопустимые символы, возможно непечатные, ака нульбайт. Попробуйте обработать строку как-то так: `filename = filename.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]", "_");`

Comment: woesss, вы были правы. Вот что я получил при выводе 'filename': '09-10 10:48:01.419 22418-22418/com.aleko2104.bloodpressure I/System.out: a�����������������������������������������������'. Там действительно есть непечатные символы, они появились при открытии буфера 'buffer = ByteArray(8192)' . Пытался воспользоваться вашим способом, но как я знаю в Котлин нет функции 'replaceAll', пытался заменить её 'replace', но без успешно. По этому теперь сохраняется два файла, один с именем, другой с его длинной. И теперь всё работает. Благодарю @woesss.

Comment: А зачем Вы в файл пишете, для таких мелких записей проще использовать `SharedPreferences`